# Error when installing Freya from USB: Invalid magic number Unaligned pointer

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive

I have tried everything, from Unetbootin, to Rufus, to LiLi, but every time I am greeted with the normal 3 option selection to try it, install it or check for disk integrity and every option returns the following.

```
Invalid magic number
Unaligned Pointer 0x9d3b0278 
Aborted. Press any key to exit.
```

My laptop is the Lenovo y50, with Intel i7 cpu and NVIDIA 860M GPU, currently running Windows 10.

I have formatted my USB several times to make sure it is on FAT32 format and I made sure that secure boot is disabled. Nothing works.

Thanks for the help

Edit: I did check the hash sum with the one listed on the support page and everything seemed in order.

Comment: I did not have to disable secure boot

Comment: @Suci Doga I did it to make sure as I was searching all the options to fiddle with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was my USB stick, changing to a cheap 5 USD one made the install go really smooth.

Comment: Your old USB stick might have had errors which caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually checked the MD5 Hash before burning to the Flashdrive?

In case you don't know: Hashing is like comparing files to check if the file is corrupt or not.

On the elementary OS Download page you can find the MD5 hash for the latest version. Get yourself a Windows MD5 Hashing Utility and check the image you just downloaded, then compare to the hash on the Download page.

Is it equal? Well, you image is not corrupt.

It's not? Even better! Just redownload and try again!

Comment: I actually did check it before and now and everything is in order. I have no idea what's wrong